# Mysql and php code skips the first result

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a web app to dysplay datas contained in a database.I wrote the code with php and mysql languages. The problem is that when my app shows datas requested by the query in a table, the first result is skipped and I can't undrestand why. 
Furthermore no error is displayed in console, that's why I can't figure the problem out.

Here you are the code, in which there is db connection, mysql query and the organization of the output in a table.

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="holder">
<h1><?php echo "<font face=verdana size=30 color=#036>SEQUENZA DI START</font>";?></h1>
</div>
<br>

<div class="container">
<?php
$conn= mysql_connect("db", "db", "ps");
if (!$conn)
{
     die("Connessione non riuscita <br>" . mysql_error());
//}else{
    //echo "Connessione al database stabilita con successo<br><br>";
}

mysql_select_db("var", $conn);

if(isset($_POST["vai"])){
   $start=$_POST["start"];
}
echo "Verranno visualizzate le varianti per la seguente sequenza di start: '<b>$start</b>'.";?>
<br><br>
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-mid-8 col-mid-offset-2">
                 <table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th><b>Codice DNA</b></th>
                          <th><b>Chr</b></th>
                          <th><b>Start</b></th>
                          <th><b>End</b></th>
                          <th><b>Alt</b></th>
                          <th><b>Ref</b></th>
                          <th><b>Zygosity</b></th>
                          <th><b>Coverage</b></th>
                          <th><b>InsertPos</b></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>   
                         <?php
                             $sql="SELECT V.dnaCode, V.Chr, V.Start, V.End, V.Alt, V.Ref, V.zygosity, V.coverage, V.InsertPos FROM variante as V WHERE V.Start='" .$start. "'";
                             $result_start = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
                             $record_start=mysql_fetch_array($result_start);
                             if($record_start==false)
                            {
                                  echo "<br>La ricerca non ha prodotto alcun risultato con la sequenza di start inserita!<br>";
                                  echo"<b>Effettuare una nuova ricerca.</b><br><br>";
                            }else
                            {

                         while ($record_start = mysql_fetch_array($result_start)) {
                             echo '
                                <tr>
                                  <td>'.$record_start["dnaCode"].'</td>
                                  <td>'.$record_start["Chr"].'</td>
                                  <td>'.$record_start["Start"].'</td>
                                  <td>'.$record_start["End"].'</td>
                                  <td>'.$record_start["Alt"].'</td>
                                  <td>'.$record_start["Ref"].'</td>
                                  <td>'.$record_start["zygosity"].'</td>
                                  <td>'.$record_start["coverage"].'</td>
                                  <td>'.$record_start["InsertPos"].'</td>
                                </tr>
                                ';

                             }
                         };
                       ?>

                    </tbody>
               </table>                       
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>


         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">         </script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ddtf.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript" >
         $('#mytable').ddTableFilter();
         </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us your code. How can we help if we cannot see yor code?

Comment: You are going to have to publish some code to have any chance of someone helping you

Comment: please, show your code

Comment: Your problem is probably in your SQL query, in which you have `WHERE V.Start='" .$start. "'"` and the value you are passing to the `$start` variable is most likely `1` instead of `0` if you want to include the first row as well; So either pass the value of `0` to `$start` or add `". $start - 1 ."` to your `WHERE` condition

Comment: If I write the same mysql query in mysql shell it shows the correct results, that's why I tought there wouldn't be problems in mysql code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### BIG NOTE
>
> Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
>    database extension in new code
>    **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
>    it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
>   If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Remove this line `$record_avsnp150 = mysql_fetch_array($result_avsnp150);` as it is fetching the first row from the resultset but you are doing nothing with it.

```
$sql_avsnp150= "SELECT A.avsnp150, V.dnaCode, V.Chr, A.Start, A.End,
                       A.Alt, A.Ref, V.zygosity, A.gene, A.Func 
                FROM annotazioni as A 
                    JOIN variante as V ON A.Start = V.Start 
                        AND A.Alt=V.Alt 
                        AND A.Ref=V.Ref 
                WHERE A.avsnp150='".$avsnp150."'";
$result_avsnp150 = mysql_query($sql_avsnp150, $conn) or die(mysql_error());;

// remove this line
//$record_avsnp150 = mysql_fetch_array($result_avsnp150);

// and change this one too
//if($record_avsnp150==false)
if($result_avsnp150 == false ) {
    echo mysqli_error();
    exit;  // serious error so no point continuing
}

if ( mysql_num_rows($result_avsnp150) == 0)    {
    echo "<br>La ricerca non ha prodotto alcun risultato con l'avsnp150 inserito!<br>";
    echo"<font color=#039><b>Effettuare una nuova ricerca.</b></font><br><br>";
}else{
    while ($record_avsnp150 = mysql_fetch_array($result_avsnp150)) {       
       echo ' 
          <tr>
            <td>'.$record_avsnp150["avsnp150"].'</td>
            <td>'.$record_avsnp150["dnaCode"].'</td>
            <td>'.$record_avsnp150["Chr"].'</td>
            <td>'.$record_avsnp150["Start"].'</td>
            <td>'.$record_avsnp150["End"].'</td>
            <td>'.$record_avsnp150["Alt"].'</td>
            <td>'.$record_avsnp150["Ref"].'</td>
            <td>'.$record_avsnp150["zygosity"].'</td>
            <td>'.$record_avsnp150["gene"].'</td>
            <td>'.$record_avsnp150["Func"].'</td>
          </tr>
          ';

       }
}
?>
```

Comment: Doing like you explained me it finally works, but there's an addictional problem. Now if the research has no results it doesn't show the message (the one called by: if($result_avsnp150 ==false)......)

Answer (score 0):

I Highly advice you not to use **mysql_query** library because it is deprecated instead use MySQLi Library or PDO extension

Here is my sample code using mysqli. I didn't check for it for error but you can see that the syntax changes.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db");

if (!$conn)
{
     die("Connessione non riuscita <br>" . mysql_error());
}

$sql="SELECT V.dnaCode, V.Chr, V.Start, V.End, V.Alt, V.Ref, V.zygosity, V.coverage, V.InsertPos FROM variante as V WHERE V.Start='" .$start. "'";

$result = $db->query($sql);
if($result){
     // Cycle through results
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       echo "
       <tr>
         <td>'.$row["dnaCode"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["Chr"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["Start"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["End"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["Alt"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["Ref"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["zygosity"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["coverage"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["InsertPos"].'</td>
       </tr>";
    }
    // Free result set
    $result->close();
}


$db->close();
```

Also you can use PDO which is also preferred by some framework developer because it is more secure(research on prepared statement) but here is a simple example for that PDO extension

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT V.dnaCode, V.Chr, V.Start, V.End, V.Alt, V.Ref, V.zygosity, V.coverage, V.InsertPos FROM variante as V WHERE V.Start='" .$start. "'");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo "
       <tr>
         <td>'.$row["dnaCode"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["Chr"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["Start"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["End"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["Alt"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["Ref"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["zygosity"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["coverage"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["InsertPos"].'</td>
       </tr>";
}
```